# simple UDP / TCP java Hangman

Tags: java, sockets, networking, tcp, udp

i have an assignment to write simple game using UDP / TCP connection. I already have a simple Hangman game on java. i want the game to be played between 2 client or between server client. this is my hangman code

```
package gameexample;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Hangman{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] words = {"writer", "that", "program"};
    // Pick random index of words array
    int randomWordNumber = (int) (Math.random() * words.length);
    // Create an array to store already entered letters
    char[] enteredLetters = new char[words[randomWordNumber].length()];
    int triesCount = 0;
    boolean wordIsGuessed = false;
    do {
    // infinitely iterate through cycle as long as enterLetter returns true
    // if enterLetter returns false that means user guessed all the letters
    // in the word e. g. no asterisks were printed by printWord
    switch (enterLetter(words[randomWordNumber], enteredLetters)) {
        case 0:
            triesCount++;
            break;
        case 1:
            triesCount++;
            break;
        case 2:
            break;
        case 3:
            wordIsGuessed = true;
            break;
    }
    } while (! wordIsGuessed);
    System.out.println("\nThe word is " + words[randomWordNumber] +
        " You missed " + (triesCount -findEmptyPosition(enteredLetters)) +
        " time(s)");
}
public static int enterLetter(String word, char[] enteredLetters)    {
    System.out.print("(Guess) Enter a letter in word ");
    // If-clause is true if no asterisks were printed so
    // word is successfully guessed
    if (! printWord(word, enteredLetters))
        return 3;
    System.out.print(" > ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int emptyPosition = findEmptyPosition(enteredLetters);
    char userInput = input.nextLine().charAt(0);
    if (inEnteredLetters(userInput, enteredLetters)) {
        System.out.println(userInput + " is already in the word");
        return 2;
    }
    else if (word.contains(String.valueOf(userInput))) {
        enteredLetters[emptyPosition] = userInput;
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println(userInput + " is not in the word");
        return 0;
        }
}

asterisks were printed, otherwise return false */
public static boolean printWord(String word, char[] enteredLetters) {
    // Iterate through all letters in word
    boolean asteriskPrinted = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        char letter = word.charAt(i);
        // Check if letter already have been entered bu user before
        if (inEnteredLetters(letter, enteredLetters))
            System.out.print(letter); // If yes - print it
        else {
            System.out.print('*');
            asteriskPrinted = true;
        }
    }
    return asteriskPrinted;
}

public static boolean inEnteredLetters(char letter, char[] enteredLetters) {
    return new String(enteredLetters).contains(String.valueOf(letter));
}


public static int findEmptyPosition(char[] enteredLetters) {
    int i = 0;
    while (enteredLetters[i] != '\u0000') i++;
    return i;
 }
}
```

can anyone show me how to write this code to client server program, with 2 player waiting turn for each guess? and the game is finished when one of them guess the last letter ?

Comment: Well... and whats the question? Small note on the network-aspect: UDP is a connection-less protocol.

Comment: thanks, edited. i know, but i kinda don't know what is best to use here.

Comment: TCP is a bit of a waste of resources, since all you need are small datagrams. On the other hand you may need to assert a level of reliability that isn't provided by UDP. Personally Id just implement an ACK-system over UDP. As for the rest you only need to provide three types of messages: initial string, selection of characters and game-over, plus optionally ACKs (if you think they are necessary).

Comment: "can anyone show me how to write this code" - Writing (or converting) a program to be client/server is no small task, and certainly too big to be covered in a single SO answer.

Comment: @paul so basically i use UDP ?

Comment: @SteveSmith oh, damn. im screwd then. well basically, ijust need the server to display the game and broadcast the response of guessed letter to 2 clients plus determine whos the winner. and move the enteredLetter method to the client side. ?!?!

Comment: @AkiJirou that's up to you. It's a design-consideration. I cant tell you to use this or that without knowing what you want. TCP would be the simplest possible solution, UDP would probably be a bit more efficient/appropriate for the situation.

Comment: IMHO, since it's a console app, I'd write it like a Telnet server, so the server is in full control and the clients just read/write text to the server.  It will make it a fair bit simpler.  I wouldn't use UDP since you'll have to take into account packet loss.  You only need UDP when speed is of the essence (e.g. for a FPS).